# JAAS and Wildfly10

Tags: tomcat, jaas, wildfly-10

I have been trying to use a custom class(`CustomLoginModule`) that implements `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule` and deploy it in wildfly 10. I have put the configurations in standalone.xml stated as below. I am not able to figure out the cause why the `CustomLoginModule` never gets invoked. I have enabled trace and able to figure out the class gets loaded from the modules directory of `Wildfly10`.

Standalone configuration:

```
 <security-domain name="xxxx">
                    <authentication>
<login-module code="com.test.CustomLoginModule" flag="required">    
<module-option name="userQuery" value="select USER_ID from FH_USER_TE where USER_ID=? and PASSWORD=?"/>

<module-option name="roleQuery" value="select ROLE from FH_USER_TE where USER_ID=?"/>                       
</login-module>
</authentication>
```

It would be great if I can get some advice/suggestions here to make it move forward.

The same worked perfectly in TOMCAT 8

Thanks,
Dwaipayan

Comment: where have you put the class CustomLoginModule?

Comment: And do you have a jboss-web.xml referencing the security domain if you deploy your app as a WAR?

Comment: Hi  simas_ch ,It is bundled or deployed with the ui.war as well as a part of the modules directory in wildfly. Also the jboss web.xml refers it as below<jboss-web>  
    <context-root>/</context-root>  
    <security-domain>fusionHiringLoginModule</security-domain>
   <disable-audit>true</disable-audit>
</jboss-web>

Comment: Can you try  <security-domain>java:/jaas/fusionHiringLoginModule</security-domain> I assume that xxxx in the code example is fusionHiringLoginModule

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried out that with java:jaas/fusionHiringLoginModule, but it failed to work. Yes xxxx and fusionHiringLoginModule is same.Do i need to declare jaas name in the standalone somewhere ? If yes where would be the appropriate place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I am able to invoke my CustomLoginModule Successfully by removing the jar from the modules directory of Wildfly 10. The .war bundles the CustomLoginModule class . I am not sure if this is the right way but it works. The options in CustomLoginModule although comes as "jboss.security.security_domain=fusionHiringLoginModule".

the sql queries have to be a part of module-option as below

<security-domain name="xxxxx" cache-type="default">
 <authentication>
 <login-module code="com.test.CustomLoginModule" flag="required">
<module-option name="userQuery" value="select userId from tableName where USER_ID=? and PASSWORD=?" />
<module-option name="roleQuery" value="select role from table where USER_ID=?"  />
</login-module>
</authentication>
</security-domain>

Thanks 

Dwaipayan
```

Comment: This is one of the ways to do it. Have a look at that for some more explanation https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingACustomLoginModuleInWildfly902

Comment: Thanks simas_ch . I think I have done with option 3. b stated in the above link. Thanks for the information. I thought probably the way I did it was not a correct approach, but the link says it all :)

Thanks